# PersonPath22 Dataset PathTrack Annotation Format

Tags: neural-network, annotations, dataset

I'm currently working with the Amazon PersonPath22 dataset. In `dataset/personpath22/raw_data/pathtrack/pathtrack_release/train` there's a bunch of folders with images and their respective annotations. Annotations are located (relative from the previously stated path) `./SOME_VIDEO_NAME/det` in a file called `det_rcnn.txt`. I'm confused by the annotation data format.

On the github repo, they say they use gluon-cv annotation format, but I think thats for a different image folder.

A line for an object would look something like `1.0,-1.0,1053.8172607421875,198.0821990966797,106.62109375,275.42665100097656,0.9953873753547668,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0`. My assumption was `<frame> <idk> <bbox min x> <bbox min y> <bbox width> <bbox height> <confidence> <X> <Y> <Z>`. But when I use those annotation parameters and convert them to COCO JSON, the bounding boxes don't match up properly to the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download ground truth data from TrackEval
   https://github.com/JonathonLuiten/TrackEval?tab=readme-ov-file
2. run below code script to parse and visualize personpath22 video & annotations

> ```
> import cv2
> import pandas as pd
>
> # File paths
> annotation_file = '/home/juma/Downloads/person_path_22_data/person_path_22/person_path_22-test/uid_vid_00008.mp4/gt/gt.txt'
> video_file = '/media/juma/data/mot-data/tracking-dataset/dataset/personpath22/raw_data/uid_vid_00008.mp4'
>
> # Read annotations
> annotations = pd.read_csv(annotation_file, header=None)
> annotations.columns = ['frame', 'id', 'x', 'y', 'w',
>                        'h', 'confidence', 'class', 'visibility', 'misc']
> print("annotations", annotations['class'].value_counts())
> # Open video
> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
> fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
> out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0,
>                       (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4))))
>
> while cap.isOpened():
>     ret, frame = cap.read()
>     if not ret:
>         break
>
>     current_frame = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
>
>     # Get annotations for the current frame
>     frame_annotations = annotations[annotations['frame'] == current_frame]
>
>     # Draw bounding boxes
>     for _, row in frame_annotations.iterrows():
>         x, y, w, h = int(row['x']), int(row['y']), int(row['w']), int(row['h'])
>         cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
>         cv2.putText(frame, f"ID:{row['class']} {int(row['id'])}", (x, y - 10),
>                     cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
>
>     # Write the frame
>     out.write(frame)
>
>     # Optional: Display the frame
>     cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
>     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
>         break
>
> # Release everything
> cap.release()
> out.release()
> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> ```